# Django Avatars stopped serving from S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-storage

Had a django project set up with the following config for displaying user avatars hosted to AWS S3 that was working for the first week of deployment, then I must have inadvertently changed some project setting or module (or something changed on S3) because now avatars requests are returning 404 (NOT FOUND).

Here's intact project setup that was originally working:

```
INSTALLED_APPS =(     
...    
'allauth',    
'allauth.account',    
'allauth.socialaccount',    
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',    
'avatar',    
...
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_AVATAR_SUPPORT ='avatar'
AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR = rel('media') 


if not DEBUG: 
     # AWS S3
     STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
     DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
     AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket'
     STATIC_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
     MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_ROOT + 'media/'
     MEDIA_URL = 'http://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'
     ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

None of this has changed and looking through recent commits I can't see anything I've done that changed the path that was working previously. Is `rel('media')` bad practice for `AVATAR_STORAGE_DIR` (but why would it work initially)?